# Thread Program in visual C++/CLI giving errors

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++-cli

I am trying to follow the tutorial at http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/ccli-threading-part-i/184402018 to do thread programming in winform in visual c++. I opened a win32 console project and added an empty cpp file to it inside which i placed the code as follows:

```
    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::Threading;

    public class ThreadX{

        int loopStart;
        int loopEnd;
        int dispFrequency;

        public:


        ThreadX(int startValue, int endValue, int frequency)
        {
            loopStart = startValue;
            loopEnd = endValue;
            dispFrequency = frequency;
        }

        void ThreadEntryPoint()
        {
            String^ threadName = Thread::CurrentThread->Name;

            for (int i = loopStart; i <= loopEnd; ++i)
            {
                if ( i % dispFrequency == 0)
                {
                    Console::WriteLine("{0} : i = {1,10}", threadName, i);
                }
            }
            Console::WriteLine("{0} thread terminating", threadName);
        }
};

int main()
{
    ThreadX o1 = gcnew ThreadX(0, 1000000,200000);
    Thread^ t1 = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(o1, &ThreadX::ThreadEntryPoint));
    t1->Name = "t1";

    ThreadX o2 = gcnew ThreadX(-1000000, 0, 200000);
    Thread^ t2 = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(o2, &ThreadX::ThreadEntryPoint));
    t1->Name = "t2";

    t1->Start();
    t2->Start();
    Console::WriteLine("Primary Thread Terminating");
}
```

However this gives me errors such as :

1. error C2726: 'gcnew' may only be used to create an object with
   managed type
2. error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot
   convert from 'ThreadX *' to 'ThreadX' No constructor could take the
   source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
3. error C3364:    'System::Threading::ThreadStart' : invalid argument for delegate    constructor; delegate target needs to be a
   pointer to a member function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing C++ and C++/CLI which is a different thing. Replace

```
public class ThreadX
```

with

```
public ref class ThreadX
```

Comment: That's exactly what the code in the listing says - copy and paste error clearly!

Comment: @doc: And please remove the following Statements, to prevent mixing of C++ and C++/CLI: `#include <iostream>    using namespace std;`

Comment: @ me? I didn't add them @user2572521 did - a catastrophic copy and paste and make extra stuff up error :-)